# Testing RCE and SSRF using Python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: server, python, vps, ssrf

Is it possible to test RCE and SSRF vulnerabilities using Python [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)? Or should I use a VPS server?

Comment: Do you want to test on the python/VPS server, or do you want to test on another site using the python/VPS server? And what is the difference between a python server and a VPS server?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to understand how those vulnerabilities works.

Example:
In RCE the attacker needs a vulnerability to run shell commands on victim server. So if you make a simple webpage in python with a small input and button where user can execute shell commands. Then you can test RCE.

Also you can create your own penetration testing lab, check these:
[Metasploitable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/metasploitable/)
[DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/)
[bWAPP](http://www.itsecgames.com/)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that using SimpleHTTPServer. It will only read and send back any existing file on the server, and a 404 error on anything else.

There's no processing at all. No script, no server-side include, no database access. Just *read that file and send back*.

And I don't know what a VPS has to do with that. A VPS is just a computer, like any other, but "in the cloud." It sits on another layer - the hardware. As such, using a VPS, a Playstation 2, a virtual machine, a docker container or a physical mainframe running Linux bare-metal does not change anything.